# What does this mean? (apt-get issue)

Tags: apt, kali-linux

```
root@kali:~# apt-get install idle
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gsettings-desktop-schemas : Breaks: mutter (< 3.19.92) but 3.18.2-1 is to be installed
 libc6-dev : Breaks: binutils (< 2.26) but 2.25.90.20160101-2 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Comment: Which bit of the text do you not understand?

Answer (score 3):

You have a mixed `sources.list` Ubuntu Xenial and kali linux

[Kali linux sources](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories)

> Any additional repositories added to the Kali sources.list file will most likely BREAK YOUR KALI LINUX INSTALL.

Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` as the documentation say:

> kali-rolling is our current active repository since the release of Kali 2016.1. Kali Rolling users are expected to have the following entries in their sources.list:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

Then run:

```
apt update
apt dist-upgrade
```